# How to become Sitecore Silver/Gold partner

Tags: partner

I am not sure is the right platform for this question or not but I am curious to know about the answer to this question so posting here.

If any Company/Organization wants to be a Sitecore Silver/Gold Partner then **What is the process to become a Sitecore Silver/Gold partner**? I have some other questions as well regarding the same, I am writing down below:

1. Should they have MVP developers?
2. Any specific criteria company should match like delivered a number of projects successfully in Sitecore, must be MVP, etc.
3. Does the individual developer/contributor can also apply for the partnership or only be a registered organization can apply?

Comment: Please note that having MVPs has nothing to do with partnership.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the page https://partners.sitecore.com/s/program-requirements you find the requirements:

[image]

Once, you meet the criteria, you have to apply for the each one of it by submitting the forms in the links in this same page.

Comment: Thanks, @João Neto, may I know the reference of the above image. Could you please provide any official Sitecore link where the above image is mentioned? So that I can share the same link with the organization, please.

Comment: This is the official link https://partners.sitecore.com/s/program-requirements.

Answer (score 0):

For the exact requirements on becoming a sitecore partner my recommandation would be to contact Sitecore Partner Team directly, available on their portal https://partners.sitecore.com/s/get-help.

From past experience I think one of the requirements on becoming an implementation partner was to have at least two certified sitecore developers in the team. For the gold partnership there are also requirements for successfull number of projects delivered, while becoming platinum partner is to also have MVP developers part of the organization.

Comment: There's no requirement for MVPs. Certified developers are required, though. Several companies listed as platinum do not have any MVPs https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/partner-finder.

Answer (score 0):

According to Sitecore Official, all partners are expected to fulfil these minimum enablement and delivery requirements to ensure customers are receiving the best possible outcomes with their Sitecore solutions.
[image]